# Is SCD_ON_DEMAND variable available for Magento 2 Open source version?

Tags: magento2.2, static-content-deploy, magento2-cloud

Can we configure global variable `SCD_ON_DEMAND` variable in `env.php` or somewhere else to mention about it for Magento 2 open source edition projects.

This `SCD_ON_DEMAND` variable is using in Magento 2.3 cloud setup. If its true then it will skips Static content deploy during build and deployment.

In Magento 2.2.x developer mode, SCD is not required at all but any settings or configuration available for open source edition so one can use for `production` mode also.

SCD - static content deploy

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you can add the next code to env.php file only manually:

```
return [
   ...
   'static_content_on_demand_in_production' => 1,
   ...
];
```